# How to create a correlation matrix of p values from the output of a dunns test?

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, dunn.test

Using the following data frame, I need to do a `dunn_test` to see which `Loc`s are different from one another according to each `var`:

```r
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- data.frame(Loc = rep(letters[1:20], each = 10),
                   ID = 1:200,
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200),
                   var6 = rnorm(200))
dat1$ID <- factor(dat1$ID)
library(rstatix)
res <- dunn_test(dat1, var1 ~ Loc)
```

How can I make a "correlation matrix of p values" between the `Loc`s from the object `res`, so that it will look like the following, and show the p values for each pairwise comparison:

```r
 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t
a 
b 
c 
d 
e 
f 
g 
h 
i 
j 
k 
l 
m 
n 
o 
p 
q 
r 
s 
t
```

Comment: My answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572690/calculate-all-the-absolute-differences-between-6-columns-of-a-table-using-mutate/62573393#62573393) shows you one technique you can use.

Comment: @Limey I worked through what you did there, im not sure how to apply it in my case but am interested in learning. would you care to demonstrate with my `res` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R approach:

```
pvals <- res$p
dst <- matrix(NA, 20, 20)
dst[lower.tri(dst)] <- pvals
dst <- as.dist(dst)
attr(dst, "Labels") <- letters[1:20]
dst <- as.matrix(dst, upper=TRUE, lower=TRUE)
dst[1:5, 1:5]
#           a          b          c          d         e
# a 0.0000000 0.54159206 0.25928005 0.33606421 0.7661024
# b 0.5415921 0.00000000 0.08212246 0.72516551 0.3639394
# c 0.2592800 0.08212246 0.00000000 0.03661193 0.4061898
# d 0.3360642 0.72516551 0.03661193 0.00000000 0.2078686
# e 0.7661024 0.36393940 0.40618977 0.20786861 0.0000000
```

You did not indicate what you wanted in the diagonal. Since these are p values, it would make sense to fill the diagonal with 1's:

```
diag(dst) <- 1
```

Comment: thanks for the help, just for pedagogical value, I was also curious what your approach (possibly just using base R) would be to specify the order of the `Loc`s. say you made the object `order` which contains the levels of `Loc` in the order that you want them to appear in the matrix:  `order <- sample(letters[1:20], replace=F)` (the example here is obviously random, but just to demonstrate a difference order for the `Loc`s). How would you do this?

Comment: [Typo in original]. It would be best to set the order before running the analysis with `dat <- dat[, order]` since it is tricky to simultaneously reorder the rows and columns of the symmetric matrix. There is a `permute` function in package `seriation` that can reorder a distance matrix if you really need to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

As requested:

```
data.frame(Group1=res$group1, Group2=res$group2, PValue=res$p) %>% 
  group_by(Group2) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from="PValue", names_from=c("Group1"))
```

Gives you a lower triangular matrix of unadjusted p-values. Swapping `Group2` and `"Group1"` (in the `group_by` and `pivot_wider` verbs) will give you an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: ahh I understand, thank a lot! Now I see how I can do something very similar to @dcarlsons procedure using tidyverse syntax, which I am still getting used to. one more question: if I wanted to specify an order in which the `Loc`s are displayed in the matrix, (e.g. `order <- sample(letters[1:20], replace=F)`, which in this case is arbitrary for demonstration), is there a way to incorporate that in the chain you wrote using tidyverse syntax?

Comment: Yes.  Create new columns in the `data.frame` at the start of the pipe that maps `Group1` and `Group2` to the order you want and use those instead of `Group1` and `Group2` in the rest of the pipe.

Comment: so this is out of the pipe, but I was trying to do: `res2 <- res%>%
  mutate(group1 = factor(group1, levels = order))%>%
  arrange(group1)` and then applying what you did to the object `res2`, which didn't work. So I haven't figured out how to do that yet, but as I was playing with it I realized your approach didn't make the upper and lower triangles occur in the same order (like a normal corr matrix with 1s in the diagonal). how would I do this differently so that the axes are in the same order as well (like what @dcarlsons example creates)?

Comment: I can't reproduce your "different order" issue.  Please supply an example.  If you look at your `res` object, each of its elements contains 190 rows, corresponding to an off-diagonal triangular matrix of values.  So my solution is an accurate representation of `res`.  To augment the output so it forms a full 400-element square matrix, create a copy of the data.frame created in the first element of the pipe, swap `Group1` and `Group2`, `rbind` the two data.frames together and then continue.  It's a one line operation.  Then fill the `NA`s in the diagonal with the values of your choice.